# Populate sheet from primary sheet column with condition

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have been trying to resolve in Excel using VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH and am hitting a dead end.

Initial conditions are:
Excel 2016 with no VBA and
No Excel 365 capabilities (so I can't use the fancy array FILTER available in Excel Online)

I have a primary sheet with child sheets.
Primary Sheet - MAIN
[image: MAIN Sheet]

Child Sheet - DAILY
[image: DAILY - Child Sheet]

All I am trying to do is read if the columns DAILY, WEEKLY or MONTHLY are set to "Yes" - then populate the respective Sheet with the data (FirstName, LastName, Team, Email) - to automate the creation of the Child Sheet - DAILY.

If any changes are made in MAIN Sheet they should automatically update the DAILY/MONTHLY/WEEKLY Sheets if it is set to Yes.

I am aware that filters may work if I keep this in one sheet - I am deliberately trying to filter this data into another Sheet.

Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , this is what I have tried using `INDEX()`, `AGGREGATE()` & `MATCH()` Functions, **[Download_Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2chT6wkQESRUxaPaRK?e=y2iNSd)**

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN!$A$2:$G$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(MAIN!$A$2:$G$6)-ROW(MAIN!$A$2)+1)/
((MATCH($E$1,MAIN!$E$1:$G$1,0)=(COLUMN(MAIN!$E$1:$G$1)-COLUMN(MAIN!$E$1)+1))*
(MAIN!$E$2:$G$6="Yes")),ROW(A1)),MATCH(A$1,MAIN!$A$1:$G$1,0)),"")
```

This one formula serves the purpose of other sheets viz. `WEEKLY` & `MONTHLY` as well, paste the formula in cell A2 and then fill down and fill across !

---

Refer screenshots for other sheets as well,

[image: WEEKLY_SHEET]

---

[image: MONTHLY_SHEET]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer Mayukh. It worked wonderfully.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you. =) I have also shared the working file, click on [Download_Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2chT6wkQESRUxaPaRK?e=VdELnS) feel free to download and follow along